# Find $P(A\cup B), P(A\cap B')$ and $P(A'\cup B')$

Tags: probability

If $P(A)=.4, P(B)=.5,$ and $P(A\cap B)=.3)$, find:

(a) $P(A\cup B)$

My solution: $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B) = .4+.5-.3=.6$

(b) $P(A\cap B')$

I know that $P(B')=1-P(B)=1-.5=.5$.

For independent events, $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$. Would this be the right attempt?

(c) $P(A'\cup B')$

I know that $P(A')=1-P(A)=1-.4=.6$ and $P(B')=.5$.

We can use $P(A'\cup B')=P(A')+P(B')-P(A'\cap B')$. How would we find $P(A'\cap B')$?

Comment: "*For* **independent events**, $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$.  *Would this be the right attempt?*"  No, that is irrelevant for the current problem since $A$ and $B$ are *not* independent.

Comment: For a corrected approach to (b) note that $P(A) = P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap B')$, following from the "law of total probability."  For (c) note that $(A'\cup B') = (A\cap B)'$

Comment: @JMoravitz ahhh i see...so $P(A\cap B')=P(A)-P(A\cap B) = .4-.3=.1$

Comment: Once you correct your typo of using `\cup` instead of `\cap`, yes that is correct for (b).  (*note: I edited in a message about (c) in my second comment*)

Comment: so for (c) if $P(A'\cup B')=P(A\cap B)'$ then $P(A\cap 
 B)'=1-P(A\cap B)=1-.3=.7$ @JMoravitz